# JQuery find only work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, find

So, we use MVC3 grid with two anchor tag in one table column.
We want that with click on a row, get anchor tag value from first table cell.
We succeed in IE*, but in Firefox and Chrome it does not work.
Here is code:

```
$("#interestTypesGrid tbody tr").live("click", function (e) {
    $("#SelectedInterestTypeID").val($(this).find('td:first a').val());
    $.post(URLGetInterestRates, $("#FormMasterData").serialize(), function (data) { $("#pagedInterestRates").html(data); });
});
```

So problem is in:

```
$(this).find('td:first a').val();
```

This only works in IE !!!

Comment: If it only works in IE, there is something terribly wrong. It should only **not** work in IE.

Answer (score 3):

`<a>` tags don't have value attributes, so `.val()` shouldn't work.

Try using `.text()` instead (you may need to `$.trim()` it).

```
$(this).find('td:first a').text()
```

Answer (score 3):

the `val` function is meant mainly for retrieving and setting the value of form elements. To get/set the contents of a non-form tag try using the [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) functions

```
$("#interestTypesGrid tbody tr").live("click", function (e) {
    $("#SelectedInterestTypeID").val($(this).find('td:first a').text());
    $.post(URLGetInterestRates, $("#FormMasterData").serialize(), function (data) { $("#pagedInterestRates").html(data); });
});
```

In this code I'm assuming that `#SelectedInterestTypeID` is a form element, if not you should change that to `text` as well.

I've tested this [working sample](http://jsbin.com/igosa3/edit) in IE and Chrome.

**Update**

The sample HTML you provided:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="/MasterData/ShowInterestTypeDetails?id=11" value="11">
            <img src = "../../Content/img/icon_detail_16px.gif" alt="" />
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>q</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>q12</td>
    <td>
        <a href="/MasterData/DeleteInterestType?id=11" value="11">
            <img src = "../../Content/img/icon_delete_16px.gif" alt="" />
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

`value` is not a valid attribute in HTML. If you're targeting HTML5 you could use a data attribute and the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function from jQuery, in fact it'd probably be easiest to put the attribute on the `tr`:

```
<tr data-interestType='{"id":11}'>
```

Then your javascript using the data function:

```
$("#interestTypesGrid tbody tr").live("click", function (e) {
    $("#SelectedInterestTypeID").val($(this).data("interestType").id);
    $.post(URLGetInterestRates, $("#FormMasterData").serialize(), function (data) { $("#pagedInterestRates").html(data); });
});
```

Another [working sample](http://jsbin.com/igosa3/2/edit) using this method.

All standards be damned you can just use the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) jquery function to retrieve the value of any arbitrary element attribute.

Comment: Thank you for good response. But problem is that in anchor tag we have img. So we need to take some value from anchor tag.
<tr><td><a href="/MasterData/ShowInterestTypeDetails?id=11" value="11"><img src = "../../Content/img/icon_detail_16px.gif" alt="" /></a></td><td>q</td><td>34</td><td>q12</td><td><a href="/MasterData/DeleteInterestType?id=11" value="11"><img src = "../../Content/img/icon_delete_16px.gif" alt="" /></a></td></tr>

Comment: Thank you for your help. I work with mvc3 grid, so i do round trip. Because value was not working, i use id of anchor tag. In that way i could take value that i need.   
$("#SelectedInterestTypeID").val($(this).find('td:first a').attr('id'));